# Facebook game page not found, did I hide it and can I get access to it again?

Tags: facebook, facebook-games

When I go to the Garden of Times game, I get redirected to a page that reads:

> You may have checked an expired link. The page you requested was not
>   found!

Did I somehow cancel this page instead of "hiding" some post?

Can I get access to the game again?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you (or someone else) blocked the game on your account.

Go to your privacy settings to see if it is blocked.

[image: List of Blocked Applications]